# Rename file with SOAP in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, updatelistitems, file, soap, rename

I use SOAP in native C++ application - no C#, no Java Script.
When renaming list item (including file) via REST, it's possible to alter `Name` field. But in case of using SOAP `Lists.asmx` `UpdateListItems` does not change neither `FileLeafRef` nor `FileRef` field though returns OK (I have tried all other possible fields from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_yeager/archive/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-internal-field-names.aspx).

Changing `BaseName` field works but does not affect extension.

Is there a way to rename file **together with extension**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible to change a files extension by changing metadata. The file have to be moved or copied to a new file with correct extension.

Check /_vti_bin/copy.asmx and /_vti_bin/lists.asmx (you can delete items with UpdateListItems)

EDIT:
You can move an item with the UpdateListItems in /_vti_bin/lists.asmx

```
<Batch OnError='Continue' RootFolder='/Shared Documents/'>
   <Method ID='1' Cmd='Move'>
      <Field Name='ID'>1</Field>
      <Field Name='FileRef'>/Shared Documents/MyFile.txt</Field>
      <Field Name='MoveNewUrl'>/Shared Documents/MyFolder/MyFile.txt</Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: OK - how to move it without copy-delete?

Comment: Seems that you can move using UpdateListItems. Updating answer.

Comment: Thanks - I know how to copy and delete the file, but how to move it? What command should I use with `UpdateListItems`?

Comment: See the example in the edit (or go directly to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.14).aspx). The key is `Cmd='Move'`

Comment: Hm... strange - I didn't find it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms459050%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Let me try...

Comment: That link is for 2007.